# How to apped a `directive` by click

Tags: angularjs

Say, I have multiple directives, on click how can i add the "directive" what i want to "popup". i have number of scenario, but using only one pop-up for all. whenever the appropiate element is clicked, using the same pop-up, i would like to update the other 'directives'

for sample, i created only one. click on the red bordered title

here is my code :

```
<div ng-controller="main">
      {{name}}

      <div class="info" ng-click="popIt()">
        <info-board></info-board>
      </div>
      <div class="popup" ng-if="show" ng-click="popIt()">
           //add directive dynamically - how?
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="modalPopup.html">
    <div class='ng-modal'>
       some information here.
    </div>
  </script>
```

js:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller("main", function($scope) {
  $scope.name = "Mo!";
  $scope.show = false;
  $scope.popIt = function (show) {
    $scope.show = !$scope.show;
  }
})

myApp.directive("infoBoard", function() {

  return {
    replace : true, 
    templateUrl: "modalPopup.html",
    scope : {},
    link : function (scope, element, attrs) {

      element.append("Hi there!")

    }
  }

})
```

[Demo Onlie](http://plnkr.co/edit/qqLy0P5iehFBVwMVe5UK?p=preview)

Comment: which directive would you like to add inside the div and how may of them? If you only want `<info-board>` be there just add it in the markup, statically.

Comment: Even, `info-board' how can i add by dynamically. for me i have 6 directives. i want to know the logic how it should be done, so i can implement for mine

Comment: Do you wish to add one of the six directives dependent on where user clicked?

Comment: Yes. that's what I am looking for exactly

Comment: well, in this case `ng-include` should work for you. Or define all six directives with `ng-if` and allow only the one you need at the moment

Comment: How to `ng-include` by condtional?  do you have any idea or article? can you post that as answer?

Comment: [ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) is conditional. You have to provide expression that will be evaluated. So define a variable in scope. When it's a valid url it will be downloaded, compiled and added to DOM